# How to add hint to bound a value in quantifiers?

Tags: dafny

```
predicate test(x: int)
{
    exists y :: x % y == 0
}
```

When I code quantifiers in a format similar to the above function, Dafny says:

> Quantifiers in non-ghost contexts must be compilable, but Dafny's heuristics can't figure out how to produce or compile a bounded set of values for 'y'.

How to fix this problem?

Also, is there any way I can learn the detailed heuristics used in Dafny to prove quantifiers? I've found them quite abstract yet lacking learning material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert this predicate into ghost predicate

```
ghost predicate test(x: int)
{
  exists y :: y > 0 && x % y == 0
}
```

These are some resources about qualifiers to better understand them

- Qualifiers in Dafny - https://dafny.org/dafny/OnlineTutorial/guide#Quantifiers
- How Dafny handles Qualifiers - https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/wiki/FAQ#how-does-dafny-handle-quantifiers-ive-heard-about-triggers-what-are-those
- How Dafny selects triggers for Qualifiers - https://pit-claudel.fr/clement/papers/dafny-trigger-selection-CAV16.pdf

Regarding proving qualifiers, it is no different than asserting method / function post condition. You assume some fixed value of bound variables with associated precondition and proceeds to prove using lemma and assert.